# UnmanagedExports equivalent c#.Core2

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-core, unmanagedexports

I'm rather new to C# and been doing a few projects in .Net Framework but been pushed towards the .Core side of things.

My question is - I was using [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) on a few of my projects to create some library's (Linux / Win) but am unable to get exports working with .Core2. I get no errors and everything compiles fine just the exports are not exposed.

I made sure that the compile arch was set to `x64`  as `any` wont build correctly. I'm assuming that the library is not compatible with .core 2 and that I need to use a different approach but am unsure what path to take. some guidance will go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [UnmanagedExports.Repack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports.Repack/). In a quick test project I can see DLL exports via Dependency Walker in a .NET Core 2.1 DLL. But I have not tested if they get called correctly because it would take me a while and the question is kind of old ;)